# Getting value from MySQL and loop over it with if

Tags: python, mysql, python-2.7, constraints, unique-constraint

I have the following piece of code:

```
### Write the new userid to the sql database
# Open database connection
db = MySQLdb.connect("sql01.domain1.lan","webuserid","test","webuserid" )
# prepare a cursor object using cursor() method
cursor = db.cursor()



dub_userid = int(userid)
# Check for dublicate of current userid value
sql = "SELECT * FROM webuserid WHERE userid = '"+str(dub_userid)+"'"
try:
        # Execute the SQL command
        cursor.execute(sql)
        # Fetch all the rows in a list of lists.
        results = cursor.fetchone()
        data = cursor.fetchone()
except:
        print "SQL Error: Unable to fetch data"
if data == None:
        print "User doesn't exist - Creating"
else:
        sys.exit("User exists")

# Prepare SQL query to INSERT a record into the database.
sql = """INSERT INTO webuserid(userid)
         VALUES ('"""+userid+"""')"""
try:
        # Execute the SQL command
        cursor.execute(sql)
        # Commit your changes in the database
        db.commit()
except:
        #Rollback in case there is any error
        db.rollback()
# disconnect from server
db.close()
```

The variable userid has a string value of 00001

What I want the code to do, is connect to the database (works), convert userid to a integer in dub_userid, and use the resulting value to look for a dublicate.

Problem is, that when I run the code, and, with userid value of 00001 the following happens:

1. Userid 1 is commited to the database (As it should, since there's no other userid called 1
2. Next run, userid 1 is commited to the database again (It shouldn't, since userid 1 already exists)
3. Third run, the scripts exists with the "User exists" message as it should.

I've tried both with data and data[1], but can't seem to figure out what's wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You really do *not* want to use string interpolation, use SQL parameters instead. Next, you are fetching *two* rows; all you really need to do is test if there are any rows:

```
sql = "SELECT * FROM webuserid WHERE userid = %s"

try:
    # Execute the SQL command
    cursor.execute(sql, (dub_userid,))
    found = cursor.rowcount
except:
    print "SQL Error: Unable to fetch data"
if not found:
    print "User doesn't exist - Creating"
else:
    sys.exit("User exists")

sql = """INSERT INTO webuserid(userid)
         VALUES (%s)"""
try:
    # Execute the SQL command
    cursor.execute(sql, (userid,))
    # Commit your changes in the database
    db.commit()
except:
    #Rollback in case there is any error
    db.rollback()
# disconnect from server
db.close()
```

This can be simplified further; you could use `db` as a context manager to commit automatically or roll back if it fails:

```
with db:
    cursor.execute(sql, (userid,))

db.close()
```

Comment: Thank you so much! That actually worked!

Shoudln't use string interpolation due to possible SQL injections?

Comment: Exactly, and SQL parameters do a much better job of properly quoting your data, as well as providing conversions if needed.

Comment: Thanks again, I'll look through my code and use the %s instead of interpolation :)

Answer (score 1):

This problem can and should be solved by adding a UNIQUE constraint to the table, not by writing Python code. If you try to enforce the constraint by writing Python code, there is still the possibility that someone inserts data by some other method. If you add a constraint, then the constraint is enforced by the database itself.

```
ALTER TABLE tablename ADD UNIQUE indexname (userid)
```

After adding this constraint, `INSERT` statements will raise an Exception if the constraint is violated. You can wrap the `cursor.execute` in a `try...except` to handle the violation.

If your table already has rows that violate the constraint, then

```
ALTER IGNORE TABLE tablename ADD UNIQUE indexname (userid)
```

will add the constraint **and** drop all rows that violate the constraint (leaving one row for each unique useid).

Comment: Didn't know mysql could do that. I'll go change that in my database. Thank you!